# list C# Employee Program

Tags: c#

I have a c# project, and I've created a class called Employees. Inside this class I have my new list:

How can i display the entire Database of the list created by me?

How can i only display the name?

Now if i type `Football` then only the names of the Employee who participated with in `Football` will be displayed

Here is the full class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

class Employee
{
    public string employeeID;
    public string Name;
    public string eventHeld;
    public int eventId;

    public Employee(string eID, string eName, string eEvents, int eId)
    {
        this.employeeID = eID;
        this.Name = eName;
        this.eventHeld = eEvents;
        this.eventId = eId;
    }

    public static void PrintDataBase() 
    {

    }

    static void Main()
    {
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
        employees.Add(new Employee("PALI_e1","Parvez Ali","FOOTBALL",1));
        employees.Add(new Employee("AALI_e2", "Ashik Ali", "FOOTBALL", 1));
        employees.Add(new Employee("AALI_e3", "Aftab Ali", "CHESS", 2));
        employees.Add(new Employee("AALI_e4", "Arif Ali", "CRICKET", 3));

        Menu.MenuPrinting();
        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease Enter Your Choice");
        string Choice = Console.ReadLine();
        foreach(Employee e in employees)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Menu
{
    public static void MenuPrinting()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main Menu");
        Console.WriteLine("=========");
        Console.WriteLine("1. DataBase");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Events Held");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Name of Emplyee");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(Employee e in filteredEmployees)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Otherwise it would output the data type of `e`. I think you mean

```
Console.WriteLine(e.employeeID + " " + e.Name + " " + e.eventID + " " + e.eventHeld);
```

Or some output similar to that

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) method to filter your collection based on a field:

```
string Choice = Console.ReadLine();
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Choice))
{
   var filteredEmployees = employees.Where(e => e.eventHeld == Choice);
   foreach(Employee e in filteredEmployees)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(e);
   }
}
```

Btw, you need to override `ToString` method for your `Employee` class otherwise you will see only your class name in the `Console`.And this example should give you an idea about how do you filter a collection based on a specific field, you can apply this logic for your other properties.

Comment: I am not able to Display database of the list.Please need some help